# Passing values among fragments through bundle

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner, new to android technology. Actually I tried to solve already existing question through different approach. I took 3 fragments in single activity, and in 1st fragment i took editText, in 2nd fragment I took button and after clicking on that button  I tried to display the fragment1 data in 3rd fragment By passing value through Bundle and I got stuck. How to do this task by this approach.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.com.dynamicfragmentproject;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        Top_fragment frg1=new Top_fragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.top,frg1);
        transaction.commit();

    }

    public void cacheData(String str) {

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        Mid_fragment frg2=new Mid_fragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.mid,frg2);
        transaction.commit();


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("editText",str);
        frg2.setArguments(bundle);
    }

    public void cacheData1(String name) {


        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        Bottom_fragment frg3=new Bottom_fragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.bottom,frg3);
        transaction.commit();


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("editText",name);
        frg3.setArguments(bundle);
    }
}
```

**fragment1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Top_fragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
package com.example.com.dynamicfragmentproject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Top_fragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText editText;
    View view;

    public Top_fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_fragment, container, false);

        editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String str = editText.getText().toString();
        MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        main.cacheData(str);

        return view;
    }
}
```

**fragment2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Mid_fragment">


   <Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
   android:text="Submit"
   android:textAllCaps="false"
   android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment2.java**

```
package com.example.com.dynamicfragmentproject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Mid_fragment extends Fragment {

    private Button buttonSubmit;
    View view;

    public Mid_fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mid_fragment, container, false);

        buttonSubmit = view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                MainActivity main1 = (MainActivity) getActivity();

                Bundle bundle = getArguments();
                String name = bundle.getString("editText");

                main1.cacheData1(name);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**fragment3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/bottom"
tools:context=".Bottom_fragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="10dp"
     />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Fragment3.java**

```
package com.example.com.dynamicfragmentproject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Bottom_fragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView viewText;
    View view;

    public Bottom_fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_fragment, container, false);

        viewText = view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String name = bundle.getString("editText");
        viewText.setText(name);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: check updated ans if any pro inform

Answer (score 0):

You need to change code in `MainActivity`, you `commit()` before set args. Change code in whole app like below

```
public void cacheData(String str) {

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    Mid_fragment frg2=new Mid_fragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("editText",str);
    frg2.setArguments(bundle);

    transaction.add(R.id.mid,frg2);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

And get data on Fragment `onCreateView`:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

> You can commit a transaction using commit() only prior to the activity saving its state (when the user leaves the activity). If you attempt to commit after that point, an exception is thrown. This is because the state after the commit can be lost if the activity needs to be restored. For situations in which it's okay that you lose the commit, use commitAllowingStateLoss().

For more detail you may refer [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

**Updated :**
In your code pass bundle value is perfect but when you get string of editext in Mid_fragment

```
getArguments().getString("editText");
```

this getting empty that's why solution is you do not need to pass Top fragment value to Mid Fragment just edittext make static like this

change `public static EditText editText`

```
Top_fragment extends Fragment {
View view;
public static EditText editText;

}
```

and `Mid_fragment` add this

```
onClick(View v) {

        if (Top_fragment.editText!=null)
        strtext=Top_fragment.editText.getText().toString();
```

here is full code of `Mid_fragment`

```
public class Mid_fragment extends Fragment {
View view;
private Button buttonSubmit;
public Mid_fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
String strtext="";
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mid_fragment, container, false);


    //strtext = getArguments().getString("editText");

    buttonSubmit = view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Top_fragment.editText!=null)
            strtext=Top_fragment.editText.getText().toString();

            MainActivity main1 = (MainActivity) getActivity();



            main1.cacheData1(strtext);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: I tried by this approach but still not getting solution.

Comment: it is possible by using Dynamic Fragment because we cannot have more than two fragments in static fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In first fragment create a object of second fragment.

```
FragmentTwo fragmenttwo=new FragementTwo();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable(object,"data")
fragmenttwo.setArguments(bundle);
```

In the second fragment

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if(bundle != null){
   SampleModel model = (SampleModel) bundle.getSerializable("data");
}
```